# Why do my icons show up as blank squares?

Tags: css, font-awesome, iis-8, woff, font-awesome-4

I've created a new (simple) website in IIS8. I've created a simple **Index.html** and put in jQuery, Bootstrap3 and Font-Awesome 4.0.0 to start playing with.

However my Font-Awesome icons show up as nothing (squares):

[image: Demo image]

**My folder structure is**

```
/
  - Index.html
  - bootstrap.css
  - bootstrap.js
  - jquery-2.0.3.js
  /css
    - font-awesome.css
  /fonts
    - FontAwesome.otf
    - fontawesome-webfont.eot
    - fontawesome-webfont.svg
    - fontawesome-webfont.ttf
    - fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

**My HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple Site</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slate.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>This is a test</h1>
        <h1>User Icon: <span class="fa-user"></span></h1>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Font-Awesome @font-face is:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**Chrome shows that no .woff file (or anything) is even downloaded** (no 404 either)

[image: Chrome network]

I've tried

- IE 11, Firefox, Chrome
- Putting the site on a live server
- Changing MIME type of .woff to

  - `font/x-woff`
  - `application/x-font-woff`
  - `application/font-woff`
  - `font/woff`
- Full read permissions to the App Pool
- Changing the url() of the @font-face from `../fonts/` to `fonts/`
- Removing all other unnecessary css and js files
- Full page refreshes, clearing cache

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I spent hours on this (too many to admit).

The problem is this code:

```
<span class="fa-user"></span>
```

Missing another `fa` in the class. It should be:

```
<span class="fa fa-user"></span>
```

Comment: I applied this way but there's still a problem. :/

Comment: you need to import this as well `@import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");`

Answer (score 3):

```
@import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
```

import this on your font awesome CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the blank square issue, but this was not the problem with my markup.  I'm using wordpress with a social comments plugin which used the same id as my fa icons were located within, and the plugin css overwrote the font-family.  So, if your class is correct make sure no other class is highjacking your font-family.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your i elements have this css styling:

```
i {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive just fixed a similar problem - icons showing as squares - with the help of Mikes answer. Turns out I had another instance of FontAwesome being loaded and this was causing issues. When I apply the font family 'FontAwesome' instead of 'Font Awesome Free 5' this fixes the issue. Specifically my problem was encountered when running the WooCommerce Product Search with Avada Theme on Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think you should get a font awesome kit by siging up in the main site then enter your email and they will send you a specfic html link tag to put it in your heade.

Then there is a problem with your code here

```
<span class="fa-user"></span>
```

casue it should be

```
<span class="fa-soild fa-user"></span>
```

then if this didn't work try switching up the tag from span to i

like this

```
<i class="fa-soild fa-user"></i>
```

and add this line also to your css

```
i {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

i hope it helped